# Is it "ok" to commit to detached head after resolving conflicts when rebasing with TortoiseGit?

Tags: rebase, tortoisegit

During a rebase, TortoiseGit gave me a list of conflicts to resolve.  I did that and tried to commit, but then it complained that I was committing to a detached head.  I was given the option to create another branch which I declined.

I've read somewhere that you don't normally want to commit to a detached head, but I read elsewhere that this is a normal part of the rebase operation.  It appeared to work fine, and nothing seems to have been lost.

Did I do the right thing committing to a detached head in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The rebase dialog has a commit button for this case - there is no need for a manual commit.

If you do a manual commit you create an additional commit in the history.